# Liquid Nitrogen Diluted Rocket

Tags: engine-design, design-alternative, booster

Imagine a rocket that uses a mixture of liquid nitrogen and oxygen as the oxidiser.

It is designed like an oxidiser-rich staged-combustion engine, however there is so much nitrogen in the mixture that all the fuel can be burned in the pre-burner without the gas becoming so hot that it melts the oxidiser pump turbine. The pre-burner then, in effect, becomes the main combustion chamber, and there is no need for a combustion chamber downstream of the oxidiser pump. It may be that there is no need for regenerative cooling channels. The engine is used on very low staging-velocity boosters where high thrust to weight is more important than exhaust velocity in achieving greater efficiency.

How would such an engine be optimised (eg. expansion ratio, isp, pressure) to achieve maximum thrust to weight ratio and minimum production and development cost?

(It's okay for it to be as low perfomance ISP-wise as a steam rocket - though probably with far better mass fraction. Perhaps optimising some-way between the ARCA steam rocket CONCEPT (i.e. on paper not reality) and a conventional chemical rocket)

Comment: How exactly do you envision reaching a high thrust to weight ratio when you sacrifice a significant part of your chamber pressure to power the turbopumps? Also, routing the entire exhaust flow through the turbine means you'll need a really big turbine and heavy piping. I guess you don't want to choke the flow anywhere before the nozzle, so you'll need really really fat pipes.

Comment: This sounds like effectively a jet engine running off pumped liquefied air. It'd have most of the complexity of a staged combustion engine (except having much less available power to push a much larger mass flow) while being outperformed by pressure-fed boosters (which aren't limited to steam rocket levels of performance).

Comment: If there's no combustion chamber, what are you pumping into? Factor out the turbopump entirely and use a pressure-fed engine. The suggestion of diluting the oxidizer with nitrogen puts me in mind of the V-2 and Redstone rockets. Those used 75%/25% alcohol/water as fuel; the water didn't contribute to combustion, so it kept combustion temperatures low while contributing mass for high thrust. Specific impulse suffered badly, so once the development of RP-1/RG-1 made regenerative cooling practical, the water-diluted fuels went by the wayside.

Comment: If the gas can not melt the turbine, then it's not hot enough for the nozzle.

Comment: I wonder what the thrust to weight ratio of the bare full-flow oxidiser pump on the raptor would be if it was fed nitrogen/oxygen and a fuel.

Comment: I actually think this is a good idea- I can't even imagine the chamber pressures you'd get with a turbo-pump setup of that size

Comment: @RussellBorogove I imagine a similar engine could be designed to use even more dilute aqueous ethanol/LOX mix than the V2 to achieve the effect the original idea was aiming for.  In the original idea, the pre-combustion chamber becomes the only combustion chamber and this is where the LN/LOX mix would be pumped like the staged combustion pump on the SpaceX Raptor. Perhaps the fuel could be electrically pumped into the (formerly-pre-combustion)-combustion-chamber.

Comment: @ReubenFarley-Hall I also like the idea of making a LOX/CO2+butane rocket for the same purpose. Lots of CO2. Perhaps, with a catalytic combustion chamber, like in a car exhaust system, one might design a very low temperature, high thrust, energy efficient 'RATO' first stage.  perhaps, the LOX could be replaced with nitrous oxide if you are a hobbyist.

Comment: @Tobe i'm not sure about the co2- it only becomes a workable liquid at high pressure, possible impractical in regards to tank strength and thus weight (i also think nitrogen would do a better job at diluting the fuel mixture), and it also wouldn't work with the catalytic converter but carbon monoxide would work very well. In fact the butane probably wouldn't even be necessary as CO already has an ISP of above 290, and if i remember it has quite a low combustion temperature. it could also operate as a substitute to a hypergolic fuel as did h2o2 in the gamma engine on the black arrow.

Comment: @Tobe perhaps something closer to what you explained in your question would be using mercury as described in john clarks book "ignition!" to dilute the fuel. it seems very counterintuitive as it is definitely on the heavier side and not helping with exhaust velocity, but despite the drastic decrease in isp, booster could get a higher delta v with this mixture due to it's ludicrous density. I also suspect it'd lower the combustion temperature a great deal, which could allow all of the exhaust product from the combustion chamber to go straight through the turbines.

Comment: @ReubenFarley-Hall perhaps ignoring the issue with the catalyst we could chill the CO2 to -56C to reduce the pressures required to about 5bar. The mercury result is intriguing. However, forgetting the CO2 as a dilutant idea, the CO fuel could be interesting. If we stick to the goal of low ISP,  for reusable side-boosters or a reusable Launch Assist stage, then one could dilute the CO/LOX rocket with liquid Nitrogen for cheap thrust. I wonder how much it would cost to produce 2km/s of dV  with solar derived CO/LOX/N2 propellant (from splitting waste CO2)  compared to LOX/Methane?

Answer (score 2):

Consider: instead of carrying a third inert propellant mixed in with the oxidizer, you could just carry an excess of fuel. At this point, you're venting most of the gas generator exhaust as rocket exhaust and diverting some to pump the propellants: the system basically reduces to a combustion tap-off cycle engine running extremely fuel-rich.

At that point, optimization would proceed as normal for such an engine...and that optimization process has always ended with much more "traditional" fuel/oxidizer ratios.

Including inert propellants for temperature control might have made sense in the earliest days of rocketry before regenerative cooling techniques were developed (and early fuels included water in large part to keep combustion temperatures down), but technology has developed far past this being a sensible trade today.

Comment: Temperature control/reduction is a helpful side effect of the idea. The main reason for the idea is to produce large amounts of impulse early and cheaply in the flight where, in conventional rockets, the exhaust velocity >> than the rocket velocity

Comment: Also it seems wasteful using fuel as reaction mass, particularly early in the flight.

Comment: exhaust velocity >> rocket velocity is super inefficient.  Maybe it would mean staging at less than 1km per second.

Comment: Purposely reducing your exhaust velocity by adding inert reaction mass may technically be more energy efficient, but all it accomplishes is reducing the total impulse, and that's what really matters in rocketry, not energy efficiency. This is not a useful trade.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff well, it's not _only_ total impulse that matters. Nitrogen could possibly make sense for getting a Big Dumb Booster cheap and reliable with high TWR. That's normally the domain of solid motors, but a nitrogen-added liquid rocket would burn much cleaner than these.

Comment: @leftaroundabout no, it would not make sense. You're adding tank mass, plumbing, pump losses, etc to carry a third fluid that reduces the effectiveness of the other propellant fluids at producing thrust. This is not making it cheaper or more reliable, and if it's displacing LOX and a heavy hydrocarbon, it's likely to *decrease* thrust, N2 having a lower molecular weight than CO2. Not that such engines are particularly known for low thrust in the first place...this is just a bad idea, originating in a misguided attempt to optimize energy efficiency over more meaningful performance measures.

Comment: N₂ having a lower molecular weight than CO₂ is an _advantage_. The lower the exhaust density, the higher the speed of sound and hence achievable exhaust speed for a given temperature. It's in the _stored_ form that high density is advantageous, and there N₂ is about the same as kerosene (and much better than hydrogen).

Comment: Higher exhaust velocity for a given exhaust power means *less thrust*. Your supposed reason for adding it was to **increase** thrust. And since you're spending power pumping LN2 into the engine instead of fuel or oxidizer, your exhaust power is actually lower. There is nothing to be gained from this scheme. Even if you want Isp more than thrust, an engine with a mixture ratio optimized for specific impulse will already have an excess of fuel in the mix, which will be more effective than N2 at reducing mean molecular mass in the exhaust while not adding all the overhead.

Comment: But you only get to enjoy “given exhaust power” if you're building your engine with good cooling in all the walls, which is a major part of what makes these engines so expensive. Short of that, the limit is on _combustion temperature_, and in that case the lower molecular mass and higher exhaust velocity results in both higher thrust and higher Isp.

Comment: You can't increase the output power using the extra cooling, because the output power is determined by the rate at which you burn fuel and oxidizer...the two propellants you're displacing by adding liquid nitrogen. You are *reducing* the output power. Everything to be gained here is already taken advantage of more simply and more effectively by using a fuel-rich O:F ratio, as is standard practice. You're only losing by adding liquid nitrogen.

Comment: It's worth noting that tripropellant rockets that effectively use *hydrogen* in this way for at least part of their burn during the transition from a dense fuel like kerosene to full-hydrogen operation have been investigated, but the added complexity has not been worth the minor improvement in performance.